# PIPE_NOWAIT breaks connetion

Tags: c++, winapi, pipe, named-pipes

I have this piece of code which represents simple pipe server. When I set `PIPE_NOWAIT` attribute and then trying to connect to it from the client with `CreateFile` function - nothing happens, we are still in the second block. When I remove `PIPE_NOWAIT` flag - we hang in the `ConnectNamedPipe` function and after `CreateFile` was called from the client we get into the first block which means we succeeded. Why so?

```
HANDLE hPipe;
std::string msg;
DWORD dwRead;

hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(L"\\\\.\\pipe\\Pipe100500",
    PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,   // FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE is not needed but forces CreateNamedPipe(..) to fail if the pipe already exists...
    PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_NOWAIT,
    1,
    1024 * 16,
    1024 * 16,
    NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
    NULL);

while (true)
{
    if (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) != FALSE)
    {
        // Waiting in the ConnectNamedPipe and then we are here
    }
    else
    {
        // always here when PIPE_NOWAIT
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [`CreateNamedPipe()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365150.aspx) documentation:

> PIPE_NOWAIT
>   0x00000001
>
> **Nonblocking mode is enabled**. In this mode, `ReadFile`, `WriteFile`, and **`ConnectNamedPipe` always return immediately**.

Per the [`ConnectNamedPipe()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365146.aspx) documentation:

> **If the specified pipe handle is in nonblocking mode, `ConnectNamedPipe` always returns immediately**. In nonblocking mode, `ConnectNamedPipe` returns a nonzero value the first time it is called for a pipe instance that is disconnected from a previous client. This indicates that the pipe is now available to be connected to a new client process. **In all other situations when the pipe handle is in nonblocking mode, `ConnectNamedPipe` returns zero**. In these situations, `GetLastError` returns `ERROR_PIPE_LISTENING` if no client is connected, `ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED` if a client is connected, and `ERROR_NO_DATA` if a previous client has closed its pipe handle but the server has not disconnected. **Note that a good connection between client and server exists only after the `ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED` error is received**.
>
> **Note  Nonblocking mode is supported for compatibility with Microsoft LAN Manager version 2.0, and it should not be used to achieve asynchronous input and output (I/O) with named pipes.**

So, to use `PIPE_NOWAIT` correctly (even though you really should not be using it at all!), you would need something more like this:

```
HANDLE hPipe;
std::string msg;
DWORD dwRead;

hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(L"\\\\.\\pipe\\Pipe100500",
    PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,   // FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE is not needed but forces CreateNamedPipe(..) to fail if the pipe already exists...
    PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_NOWAIT,
    1,
    1024 * 16,
    1024 * 16,
    NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
    NULL);

if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL))
        {
            // pipe has been disconnected and is now available to be connected to again...
        }
        else
        {
            switch (GetLastError())
            {
                case ERROR_PIPE_LISTENING:
                    // no client is connected...
                    break;

                case ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED:
                   // a client is now connected...
                   break;

                case ERROR_NO_DATA:
                    // a previous client has closed its pipe handle but the server has not disconnected yet...
                    DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe);
                    break;

                default:
                    // fatal error...
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise, do what the documentation says and don't use `PIPE_NOWAIT` at all.  Use Overlapped I/O instead if you don't want `ConnectNamedPipe()` to block.  MSDN provides examples of that:

[Named Pipe Server Using Overlapped I/O](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365603.aspx)

[Named Pipe Server Using Completion Routines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365601.aspx)